# How can i add glyphicons to my navbar items?

Tags: html, navbar, glyphicons

I want to add a glyphicon before my navbar items, just like in this page:
http://skywarriorthemes.com/arcane/landing/

Here is my navbar:
HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li class="navfixborder"><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

full with css:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lystef91/

Comment: That page is using [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io) which is a popular choice for this.

Comment: Use http://fontawesome.io/icons/  `Font Awesome Icons `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using bootstrap. If that's the case [Go to this link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) and add those classes just like the following.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style = "color : #e98fa0;"></i>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire" style = "color : #e98fa0;"></i>Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style = "color : #e98fa0;"></i>Page 2</a></li>
                    <li class="navfixborder"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf" style = "color : #e98fa0;"></i>Page 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Check the docs!

http://getbootstrap.com/components/ gives this example:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Assuming you've got the icons included into your page/css already. This will depend on your setup; if you've just installed bootstrap off the shelf, I believe that includes the icons. If I've misunderstood and you're not using bootstrap, the instructions will still be roughly the same. Most icon fonts like this use classes on empty elements, and whichever one you're using will show which class goes to which icon on their demo pages.

Answer (score 1):

### There Is 2 Way To Do This.

> **1 ) IN Case Of Using `bootstrap` Then Use Bootstrap `icons` Go to below Link: and Just Add Given Classes**
>
> http://getbootstrap.com/components/
>
> **NOTE:** First Add below Bootstrap glyphicon cdn: [LINK](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

> **Example With Bootstrap Glyphicon:**

```css
a{

 text-decoration: none;

}

.nav {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #101014;
}

.nav>li.disabled>a {
  color: #777;
}

.nav>li.disabled>a:hover,
.nav>li.disabled>a:focus {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav .open>a,
.nav .open>a:hover,
.nav .open>a:focus {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-color: #337ab7;
}

.nav .nav-divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.nav>li>a>img {
  max-width: none;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs>li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
  border-color: #eee #eee #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  color: #555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a,
.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a,
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:hover,
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:focus {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
  }
}

.nav-pills>li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-pills>li>a {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.nav-pills>li+li {
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.nav-pills>li.active>a,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}

.nav-stacked>li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-stacked>li+li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.nav-justified {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-justified>li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-justified>li>a {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-justified>.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-justified>li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .nav-justified>li>a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.nav-tabs-justified {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-tabs-justified>li>a {
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.nav-tabs-justified>.active>a,
.nav-tabs-justified>.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs-justified>.active>a:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs-justified>li>a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  }
  .nav-tabs-justified>.active>a,
  .nav-tabs-justified>.active>a:hover,
  .nav-tabs-justified>.active>a:focus {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
  }
}

.tab-content>.tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content>.active {
  display: block;
}

.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: left;
  }
}

.navbar-collapse {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
  max-height: 340px;
}

@media (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
}

.container>.navbar-header,
.container-fluid>.navbar-header,
.container>.navbar-collapse,
.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container>.navbar-header,
  .container-fluid>.navbar-header,
  .container>.navbar-collapse,
  .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-static-top {
  z-index: 1000;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-static-top {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-fixed-top,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  top: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-brand:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar>.container .navbar-brand,
  .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
}

.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.navbar-toggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar+.icon-bar {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin: 7.5px -15px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    background-image: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .9em;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Roboto, 'Open Sans', Arial;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-left: 2px solid #333240;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 45px;
    padding-left: 45px;
  }
}

.navbar-form {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-form .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .form-control-static {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navbar-form .input-group {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-addon,
  .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-btn,
  .navbar-form .input-group .form-control {
    width: auto;
  }
  .navbar-form .input-group>.form-control {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-form .control-label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .radio,
  .navbar-form .checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .radio label,
  .navbar-form .checkbox label {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .navbar-form .radio input[type="radio"],
  .navbar-form .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .navbar-form .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
    top: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-form .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .navbar-form .form-group:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-form {
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-btn {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.navbar-btn.btn-sm {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.navbar-btn.btn-xs {
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.navbar-text {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-text {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-left {
    float: left !important;
  }
  .navbar-right {
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
  .navbar-right~.navbar-right {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #5e5e5e;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #333;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.disabled>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.disabled>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.disabled>a:focus {
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #888;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #777;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:focus {
    color: #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-default .btn-link {
  color: #777;
}

.navbar-default .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-default .btn-link:focus {
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-default .btn-link[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-default .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-default .btn-link[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-default .btn-link:focus {
  color: #ccc;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #2a2a34;
  border: 2px solid #3b3a4a;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-text {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #212129;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
  background-color: #212129;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.disabled>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.disabled>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.disabled>a:focus {
  color: #444;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #333;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
  border-color: #101010;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3b3a4a;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.dropdown-header {
    border-color: #3b3a4a;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
    background-color: #3b3a4a;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #9d9d9d;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3b3a4a;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:focus {
    color: #444;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-link {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .btn-link {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}

.navbar-inverse .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-inverse .btn-link:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .btn-link[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-inverse .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-inverse .btn-link[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-inverse .btn-link:focus {
  color: #444;
}

.navfixborder {
  border-right: 2px solid #333240;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> HOMEPAGE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cd"></i> TEAM WARS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i>  GAMING NEWS</a></li>
        <li class="navfixborder"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star">  </i> FORUMS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cd"></i>  SHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>  BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>  CONTACT</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

---

> **2) IN Case Of Using `font Awesome` Then Go to below Link:**
>
> http://fontawesome.io/icons/
>
> **NOTE:** First Add below Font Awesome Library and See The Example of Used:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

> **Example with FontAwesome:**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-sm" aria-hidden="true"></i> HOMEPAGE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa fa-trophy fa-sm"></i> TEAM WARS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-sm"></i>  GAMING NEWS</a></li>
        <li class="navfixborder"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users fa-sm">  </i> FORUMS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-sm"></i>  SHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book fa-sm"></i>  BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-sm"></i>  CONTACT</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example for you (using font font-awesome/4.7.0).

Just two step to use it:

1st reference the font-awesome lib:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

2nd add to each of your menu item like:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>
```

```css
.nav {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #101014;
}

.nav>li.disabled>a {
  color: #777;
}

.nav>li.disabled>a:hover,
.nav>li.disabled>a:focus {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav .open>a,
.nav .open>a:hover,
.nav .open>a:focus {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-color: #337ab7;
}

.nav .nav-divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.nav>li>a>img {
  max-width: none;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs>li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
  border-color: #eee #eee #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  color: #555;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a,
.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a,
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:hover,
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a:focus {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
  }
}

.nav-pills>li {
  float: left;
}

.nav-pills>li>a {
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.nav-pills>li+li {
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.nav-pills>li.active>a,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
}

.nav-stacked>li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-stacked>li+li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.nav-justified {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-justified>li {
  float: none;
}

.nav-justified>li>a {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-justified>.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-justified>li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }
  .nav-justified>li>a {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.nav-tabs-justified {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-tabs-justified>li>a {
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.nav-tabs-justified>.active>a,
.nav-tabs-justified>.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs-justified>.active>a:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs-justified>li>a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  }
  .nav-tabs-justified>.active>a,
  .nav-tabs-justified>.active>a:hover,
  .nav-tabs-justified>.active>a:focus {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
  }
}

.tab-content>.tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content>.active {
  display: block;
}

.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: left;
  }
}

.navbar-collapse {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.navbar-collapse.in {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
  max-height: 340px;
}

@media (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
}

.container>.navbar-header,
.container-fluid>.navbar-header,
.container>.navbar-collapse,
.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container>.navbar-header,
  .container-fluid>.navbar-header,
  .container>.navbar-collapse,
  .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-static-top {
  z-index: 1000;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-static-top {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-fixed-top,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  top: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-brand:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar>.container .navbar-brand,
  .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
}

.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.navbar-toggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar+.icon-bar {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin: 7.5px -15px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    background-image: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .9em;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Roboto, 'Open Sans', Arial;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-left: 2px solid #333240;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 45px;
    padding-left: 45px;
  }
}

.navbar-form {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-form .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .form-control-static {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navbar-form .input-group {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-addon,
  .navbar-form .input-group .input-group-btn,
  .navbar-form .input-group .form-control {
    width: auto;
  }
  .navbar-form .input-group>.form-control {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-form .control-label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .radio,
  .navbar-form .checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .navbar-form .radio label,
  .navbar-form .checkbox label {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .navbar-form .radio input[type="radio"],
  .navbar-form .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .navbar-form .has-feedback .form-control-feedback {
    top: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-form .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .navbar-form .form-group:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-form {
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-btn {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.navbar-btn.btn-sm {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.navbar-btn.btn-xs {
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.navbar-text {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-text {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-left {
    float: left !important;
  }
  .navbar-right {
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
  .navbar-right~.navbar-right {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #5e5e5e;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #333;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.disabled>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.disabled>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.disabled>a:focus {
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #888;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #777;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:focus {
    color: #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-default .btn-link {
  color: #777;
}

.navbar-default .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-default .btn-link:focus {
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-default .btn-link[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-default .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-default .btn-link[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-default .btn-link:focus {
  color: #ccc;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #2a2a34;
  border: 2px solid #3b3a4a;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-text {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #212129;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
  background-color: #212129;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.disabled>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.disabled>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.disabled>a:focus {
  color: #444;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #333;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
  border-color: #101010;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3b3a4a;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.dropdown-header {
    border-color: #3b3a4a;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .divider {
    background-color: #3b3a4a;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #9d9d9d;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3b3a4a;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:hover,
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>.disabled>a:focus {
    color: #444;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-link {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .btn-link {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}

.navbar-inverse .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-inverse .btn-link:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .btn-link[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-inverse .btn-link:hover,
.navbar-inverse .btn-link[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .navbar-inverse .btn-link:focus {
  color: #444;
}

.navfixborder {
  border-right: 2px solid #333240;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li class="navfixborder"><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```